# Change default network adapter to the VPN one in Windows 7

Tags: vpn, windows

OpenVPN was working yesterday, but today is not working anymore. In a cmd windows I typed:

```
tracert www.google.com
```

The result tell me that the route is through the wireless adapter (192.168.0.1) instead the VPN adapter (10.12.0.134):

```
 1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
 2    11 ms     9 ms     9 ms  ...
```

The OpenVPN Service is running. The connection with the VPN Server is active (I'll paste the current status at the end of this post).

**How could I change the default route of the packets to the VPN Adapter?**

Screenshot of the VPN adapter:

[image: Screenshot of the VPN adapter]

Current status of OpenVPN:

```
Wed Oct 09 01:24:57 2013 OpenVPN 2.3.2 i686-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [IPv6] built on Aug 22 2013
Wed Oct 09 01:24:57 2013 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Wed Oct 09 01:24:57 2013 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Wed Oct 09 01:24:58 2013 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Wed Oct 09 01:24:58 2013 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Wed Oct 09 01:24:58 2013 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Wed Oct 09 01:24:58 2013 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Wed Oct 09 01:24:58 2013 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Wed Oct 09 01:24:58 2013 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Wed Oct 09 01:24:58 2013 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are running on Windows
Wed Oct 09 01:24:58 2013 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Wed Oct 09 01:24:58 2013 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]46.23.68.180:80
Wed Oct 09 01:24:58 2013 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1381253098,TCP_CONNECT,,,
Wed Oct 09 01:24:59 2013 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]46.23.68.180:80
Wed Oct 09 01:24:59 2013 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Wed Oct 09 01:24:59 2013 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]46.23.68.180:80
Wed Oct 09 01:24:59 2013 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1381253099,WAIT,,,
Wed Oct 09 01:24:59 2013 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1381253099,AUTH,,,
Wed Oct 09 01:24:59 2013 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]46.23.68.180:80, sid=44066d31 2c78cdb4
Wed Oct 09 01:24:59 2013 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Wed Oct 09 01:25:05 2013 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=CH, ST=Zurich, L=Zurich, O=vpnbook.com, OU=IT, CN=vpnbook.com, name=vpnbook.com, emailAddress=admin@vpnbook.com
Wed Oct 09 01:25:05 2013 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=CH, ST=Zurich, L=Zurich, O=vpnbook.com, OU=IT, CN=vpnbook.com, name=vpnbook.com, emailAddress=admin@vpnbook.com
Wed Oct 09 01:25:08 2013 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Wed Oct 09 01:25:08 2013 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Oct 09 01:25:08 2013 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Wed Oct 09 01:25:08 2013 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Oct 09 01:25:08 2013 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Wed Oct 09 01:25:08 2013 [vpnbook.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]46.23.68.180:80
Wed Oct 09 01:25:09 2013 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1381253109,GET_CONFIG,,,
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 SENT CONTROL [vpnbook.com]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS  83.170.64.2,dhcp-option DNS  83.170.69.2,route 10.12.0.1,topology net30,ping 5,ping-restart 30,ifconfig 10.12.0.154 10.12.0.153'
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1381253111,ASSIGN_IP,,10.12.0.154,
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 open_tun, tt->ipv6=0
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 TAP-WIN32 device [Conexión de área local 2] opened: \\.\Global\{CB466069-F4E3-4105-9365-33F10807AFCC}.tap
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.9 
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.12.0.154/255.255.255.252 on interface {CB466069-F4E3-4105-9365-33F10807AFCC} [DHCP-serv: 10.12.0.153, lease-time: 31536000]
Wed Oct 09 01:25:11 2013 NOTE: FlushIpNetTable failed on interface [21] {CB466069-F4E3-4105-9365-33F10807AFCC} (status=5) : Acceso denegado.  
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 TEST ROUTES: 2/2 succeeded len=1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 46.23.68.180 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry: Acceso denegado.   [status=5 if_index=10]
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 Route addition fallback to route.exe
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 env_block: add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 ERROR: Windows route add command failed [adaptive]: returned error code 1
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.12.0.153
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry: Acceso denegado.   [status=5 if_index=21]
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 Route addition fallback to route.exe
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 env_block: add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 ERROR: Windows route add command failed [adaptive]: returned error code 1
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.12.0.153
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry: Acceso denegado.   [status=5 if_index=21]
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 Route addition fallback to route.exe
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 env_block: add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 ERROR: Windows route add command failed [adaptive]: returned error code 1
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1381253113,ADD_ROUTES,,,
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 10.12.0.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.12.0.153
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry: Acceso denegado.   [status=5 if_index=21]
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 Route addition fallback to route.exe
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 env_block: add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 ERROR: Windows route add command failed [adaptive]: returned error code 1
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 Initialization Sequence Completed
Wed Oct 09 01:25:13 2013 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1381253113,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.12.0.154,46.23.68.180
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see a sample configuration at [University of Twente](http://www.utwente.nl/icts/en/handleidingen/vpn/win7/) website. The place that you need to set the default gateway is shown specifically in the image for default gateway:

[image]

Comment: Hello. As it stands, your post is kind of short and fails to really answer OP's question. Depending upon who you ask, it might work as a partial answer, but I'd try posting input such as this as a comment for now on. See our [help center](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info on writing good answers.

Comment: Could you please tell me where is that option in Windows XP? I tried to find something in Windows 7 with no luck.

Comment: I have updated the solution. I hope its of help

Comment: First, sorry: I didn't receive any notification of superuser.com telling me you updated your question! The solution you propose doesn't work in my case because it uses the PPTP protocol, and it is blocked in some countries like the one I'm now. That's why I have to use OpenVPN.